# awk searching strings from file

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm currently using

```
 $ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($3 in a)' find.txt path_to_100_files/*
```

which uses find.txt strings to search multiple files within path_to_100_files/ for matches.

find.txt contains

```
123@hotmail.com
1235@hotmail.com
```

and then path_to_100_files/ contains files such as

```
0.0.0.0:002921931:123@hotmail.com
123.0.0.1:00029382:1235@hotmail.com
```

now what this is doing is only searching the 3rd column for the strings from find.txt, but i need it to search the entire file/every column?

as some files may be 5 columns long, or 9 columns long example,

```
0.0.0.0:002921931:1111111:123@hotmail.com
123.0.0.1:00029382:1111111:11111:1235@hotmail.com
```

I've tried to change ($3 in a) to like ($0-$9 in a) but doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

Why search fields one-by-one?  Why not search whole lines at a time?

```
grep -f find.txt path_to_100_files/*
```

Comment: You should add a `-F` as well for fixed-string search.

Comment: @Wildcard As well as add a `-o` to only output matches.

Answer (score 0):

If the email is the last field in the 100 files, use:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($NF in a)' find.txt path_to_100_files/*
```

If you must look into each field, you need a loop:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i in a) {print;break}}} find.txt path_to_100_files/*
```

But the simpler call is using grep:

```
grep -oFf find.txt path_to_100_files/*
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the maximum column exsists in the files using below command and take the maximum value  from it

```
k=`awk -F ":" '{print NF}'  path_to_100_files/*  | sort -nr | head -1`
```

Used for loop to get it checked with every column

```
for ((i=0;i<=$k;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" -F ":" 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}($i in a) {print }’   find.txt path_to_100_files/*   ; done
```